# Discounts on AWS bills

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I wish to check on my monthly AWS bills, what are the discounts applied. I can only check credits applied over the total amount. Is there any other method that I can check what are the types of discounts applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cost Explorer you can group by "Charge Type" to see what is being reduced (if any) from your overall usage. You can also use the "Charge Type" filter:

[image]

You might also have private prices from contracts which is already reflecting in the "Usage" section. If you have the contracts, you can already review it and see the private rates for the product.

If you just know you have private pricing on a service but don't have access to the contract, you can go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/bills and check the item description. For example, if you have a private pricing for standard storage in S3, you can check the bills page, open "Simple Storage Service" and check the description of "Standard Storage":

[image]

By the way, if you're using the CUR in any way, you have a column in the report called lineItem_UnblendedRate you can use to understand the prices for each item (also shows in the lineItem_LineItemDescription column)